# Url Rewrite not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change this  url from :

```
 Site.com/Controller/myController.php?action=myAction&var1=y&var2=z
```

to :

```
 Site.com/myAction/var1/y/var2/z/..../varn/valn
```

Variables can be present or not.

No redirection

I tried many solutions but what i have done is just replacing Controller/myController.php with items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^items/(.*)$ Controllers/myController.php$1
```

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# recursion to replace /action/n1/v1/n2/v2 to QUERY_STRING
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(/.*)?$ Controllers/myController.php$2?action=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(Controllers/myController\.php)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ $1$4?$2=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Not working , i added the Controller folder , but still not working

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ Controllers/ebooksController.php?action=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [L,QSA,NC]`

my htaccess is empty , i added this  rule with and without Controllers folder , and then tried to access this page  :

     site.com/home 

it should show the content of :

     site.com/Controllers/myController.php?action=home

Comment: Sorry , but this works only for fixed number of parameters (0 and 4 here)  , i need a dynamic one , depending of the number of get variables , sometimes , no one , sometimes 2 ,3 ....

Comment: Wow you totally changed the nature of the question in your last edit :)

Comment: sorry , it's my fault , i haven't put all details in the post , i will test this and tell you

Comment: thank uu , it works as expected , if you have time   , please do some comments

Comment: RewriteCond %REQUEST_FILENAME ! -d
RewriteCond %REQUEST_FILENAME ! -f

Comment: Sorry didn't what you mean by your last comment. I will add explanation in answer after work hours today.

Comment: Your htaccess made a problem , files ( css , imgs , js ) not work anymore , i added condition to exclude them from rewriting